# Display Wordpress blog article category

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using Wordpress theme Bridge, here's the [reference](https://bridgelanding.qodeinteractive.com).

I'm using the masonry blog shortcode on my website's homepage. It currently only shows the blog title, excerpt, metadata, and comments and I would like to show the blogs category/categories.

The below shows the code that displays the title, blog excerpt, metadata and comments, so any help to display blog category would be appreciated.

```
$html .= '<div class="q_masonry_blog_post_text">';
$html .= '<'.$title_tag.' itemprop="name" class="q_masonry_blog_title
entry_title"><a itemprop="url" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' .
get_the_title() . '</a></'.$title_tag.'>';
$excerpt = ($text_length > 0) ? substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,
intval($text_length)) : get_the_excerpt();
$html .= '<p itemprop="description" 
class="q_masonry_blog_excerpt">'.$excerpt.'...</p>';
$html .= '<div class="q_masonry_blog_post_info">';
if ($display_time != "0") {
$html .= '<span itemprop="dateCreated" class="time entry_date updated">'.
get_the_time('d F, Y') .'<meta itemprop="interactionCount" 
content="UserComments: <?php echo get_comments_number(qode_get_page_id()); 
?>"/>.</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get_the_category`.

Here you find it [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/).

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
$html .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>'
 }
$html .= '</div>'; //closing class q_masonry_blog_post_info
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use this code to get category in post.

```html
<?php 
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){
        echo $category->name;
        }
    ?>
```